# I want to check the storage used by GKE Node

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have created a GKE cluster with 20 GB of storage and it is runnning 4 pods. 3 of them are angular application and 1 is node applicaiton and 10.5GB is already used and only 3.96 GB is left. I wanted to check how much storage is used by whom these 4 pods cannot use that much of storage i think. Is there any way to check how and who is using the storage

Also the images pulled by this node is stored in which location. Here are the screenshot

Storage screenshot
[image]

No ephemeral-storage is being used.

Ephemeral status
[image]

I wanted to know where is the storage being used i don't think 4 pods use that much of storage so please someone guide me to check the status of storage